How can I Align an existing Object to the 3D Viewport's XY Plane?
When adding a Plane object, it currently aligns with the world’s X-Y plane at the 3D Cursor's location and can be aligned to the X-Y plane of the active 3D Viewport using this method. This method only works when newly adding objects. But what if the object already exists. How can I achieve this without scripting? I saw this thread but I don't quite understand the steps and not sure if the "Object to viewport" part answers this question. Perhaps more details with screenshots are required for me to understand it.


The only way I found so far is to use Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation, then from the options choose View.


Nice! Totally forgot about this menu item. Or set the Transformation Orientation to View and then do the Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation

Nice that works too. I only tried changing the transform orientation to View and then clearing rotation with Alt+R, which sadly doesn't work, but that does.

Clearing the rotation with Alt+R only works by resetting to the object's local frame of reference, which would be either the world or a parent object if it was the child of something. A transformation orientation is not a frame of reference (i.e. a local or global coordinate system), it is basically a conversion of orientation-aligned transforms to transforms/coordinates in the frame of reference.
